# Can I set AppCompat version greater than Design version in app.gradle file in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I tried to set the AppCompat version to '25.0.2' and Design version to '25.+'
This was showing as an error under AppCompat, with RunTime crashes as message.

Please let me know if it is possible to have different SDK values.

Comment: But why do you have to?

Comment: To save you time, version 25.3.1 is the last version of support library *(all of them)* that doesn't crash on Samsung Android 4 because of [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63151548).

Answer (score 3):

You should always use the **same version** for your support libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different version of support library, ***but you should not!***. Because, as the error says, it will lead to a runtime crash. Why? Because when you using **design** version to `'25.+'` it means that you want to use the most recent of version 25 which is `25.3.1`. But you use **appcompat** `25.0.2`. It will introduce some bugs because support design is depend on appcompat implicitly. So, when you add the support design dependency, the appcompat will be implicitly included in your dependency.

You can verify that by looking at gradle dependency tree with:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

When you using a different support library version for design and appcompat, there is a probability that the design library need an api that is not in the previous appcompat version yet. So, it will lead to a runtime crash.